# does anyone know this encryption method

Tags: http

I'm sniffing the http requests of a mobile app. When the app opens, it sends a request to https://mobile.useinsider.com/api/v3/session/start and starts a session. When you close the application, it sends a request to https://mobile.useinsider.com/api/v3/session/stop and ends the session.

It sends a data in the payload section, this data goes encrypted, as a result of many efforts, I could not find the encryption method, can you help me with this? I leave you a sample encryption

```
{"payload":"UEt+QlFWe0JudWVBbQBYWXpSWlt5SFdSe2Z5B2pvcAJ5SFhAb3Z6WH5RfEF9X30JVgFmRFFuDF5Q\nX2VNUXp5W3xUQQV9X2UKb2UBAjlgBwdcUGRtXH1deElibXxOU2QBQGoHfANhbXgEe1pPXGhsaF9a\nW2BSUXR+TGtjA0lxX0IDVGBPXFZzXkdibXwEa2QJQnteXUt2X1EBOHx8bEp6ZmINU2FMBXpVYwBu\nZQYIbQABWlFvYFt7W3lXVwAFXmsLZ1puS3pLfF9iAGlvAAJsAXFQVl9yRlBBfARRAQNLfFxmQlFv\nY0g+VnR+QVF3ewV1YWsHfWdfB39gZwN3bQNQfnByQmtseANaWGRNagENXVBjZ1p3XHhHawBcXVNj\nRkNZB1ldfnByXlNjYFVhbWAEUV5UXDhQamFUVgMNWFJ\/c0duAGZRel9uWlFwe154cXlIVgMNX1Jg\nf0hQdApBUWUAW3xVb1pWen1UeXF+SGlge0hVZQpNbQBmA1BVcwJVZQpNP3teXUp1YVVHe15qWVZZ\nXlliYwtcVntqTFNjeAJccmROe1lIAntZdERbcwsGaGtyT1NjC0ZxX11df0oMT35eZwFxXEVdU2t2\nU1NscFUyb3VYSGpvf0FuZWJRel9uWlFwe154cXkIVGUFXlZVDEduYXoOfFlyX1BVWVhtZEROYV9y\nQlBVDFtVYXpLfF8NSGsLb15XXH1IVwAAWzl3XHsHfll9QH9de0BxWF5OagFAQ2sGdANZYgtBagFq\nRVEGdFpacmRfe1lIWGtjSkliZkVdUXRAXVZzaEVbWAJdfVpyd1BZYEpaB15fOHpRQlttAHVBVl9Y\nXlBRfAR9XmEJVl9AWGlvTUF9W0RRVnpiSFJ+DF5WX3VRV3ViWXpSRQJXXGVUeXF+RVBVDABVZWFU\nVlt9BHpVUUQ+UAFcRmhne0BxWEpCawF+BVNjC0ZgB2RBa2RyRmhjY1p3WGhcUHt2WX53eFhibWhE\nawFuU1ZzC0FiYgZdfVpyWWFgfGJZYXhGa2V+bDhmAl9yb2VYfmULRVR6AF9wellyY2JsXkptWVt9\nUUhye2VtBERmZENsVl8NamkKRUNWZGl8VGdia1J\/Y19QAgZpe0hyR2AJb2pQA2FtP2EEVnFcY1pf\nV2QBWVN8WUdZX1pcaHtcfmoHfGt2fUJMfWR+d3xwXnBrBHgAY1gJA2tieAVscGBNZ3QNX1ZYZ0lc\nckFNfwJcY2AFfFUyY2pEYGpUc2RVdFsLZlx6Rml\/b0J5XmlxYF5mX2EJZwNhAUNveHpYRVdRBEp6\ndV9Ab1l9AnpRQltXAGFKbQFuXlBWe0JWAAdRelt9Sjl1TAYFfll9XH53eERhYnxGa2RcWWoGB1ta\nYmddfVpyX1AGAkZacnwHa2RUR1NjRkN0WHRBaHtyQ1NjY1p0dnhEaHRiB3teXVp1T1ZeOH1seAdt\nZXYIeEhfSml8e1h5W3pLfF8FRGl\/Y0F9WFxRZGR6ZGYJDFN5ZnVqZ3F9QXpVZ15QX19Sb2QNQWpv\nAFxQZXVWb2F9BHpWZ0s+e1pPXFZjYENidnsCe1l1BmtOZ0l3YnRcfHd1AH9jY0lhT3tdVGBPXFZj\nYENidnsCe1l1BmtOZ0l3YnRcfHd1AH9jY0lhT3tdfnByBThVZQJUVgFmWlFgdFt7WHYKe0hfBn1S\ncAF6WGkBPw==\n"}
```

I'm sniffing the http requests of a mobile app. When the app opens, it sends a request to https://mobile.useinsider.com/api/v3/session/start and starts a session. When you close the application, it sends a request to https://mobile.useinsider.com/api/v3/session/stop and ends the session.

It sends a data in the payload section, this data goes encrypted, as a result of many efforts, I could not find the encryption method, can you help me with this? I leave you a sample encryption

```
{"payload":"UEt+QlFWe0JudWVBbQBYWXpSWlt5SFdSe2Z5B2pvcAJ5SFhAb3Z6WH5RfEF9X30JVgFmRFFuDF5Q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\ncAF6WGkBPw==\n"}
```

Comment: Your question is repeated twice - please edit to as the question just once.

Also when you say "as a result of many efforts", what did you try? I see this is base64, but maybe you already tried base64. Are you sure it's encrypted and not just a binary protocol?

Also, it helps to explain what your broader goal is. Why are you trying to figure out the encryption method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first step, this is no encryption:

- The string of the "payload" is base64 encoded data.
- It is delimited by the linefeed `\n` meta-character every 76 characters like in mime conforming e-mails.
- Any `/` is escaped like this `\/`.

Reversing all this:

```
payload='{"payload":"UEt+QlFWe0JudWVBbQBYWXpSWlt5SFdSe2Z5B2pvcAJ5SFhAb3Z6WH5RfEF9X30JVgFmRFFuDF5Q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\ncAF6WGkBPw==\n"}'

echo $payload | sed 's/.*":"//; s/".*//; s/\\n//g; s|\\/|/|g' | base64 -d - >payload.bin

hexdump -C payload.bin

00000000  50 4b 7e 42 51 56 7b 42  6e 75 65 41 6d 00 58 59  |PK~BQV{BnueAm.XY|
00000010  7a 52 5a 5b 79 48 57 52  7b 66 79 07 6a 6f 70 02  |zRZ[yHWR{fy.jop.|
00000020  79 48 58 40 6f 76 7a 58  7e 51 7c 41 7d 5f 7d 09  |yHX@ovzX~Q|A}_}.|
00000030  56 01 66 44 51 6e 0c 5e  50 5f 65 4d 51 7a 79 5b  |V.fDQn.^P_eMQzy[|
00000040  7c 54 41 05 7d 5f 65 0a  6f 65 01 02 39 60 07 07  ||TA.}_e.oe..9`..|
00000050  5c 50 64 6d 5c 7d 5d 78  49 62 6d 7c 4e 53 64 01  |\Pdm\}]xIbm|NSd.|
00000060  40 6a 07 7c 03 61 6d 78  04 7b 5a 4f 5c 68 6c 68  |@j.|.amx.{ZO\hlh|
00000070  5f 5a 5b 60 52 51 74 7e  4c 6b 63 03 49 71 5f 42  |_Z[`RQt~Lkc.Iq_B|
00000080  03 54 60 4f 5c 56 73 5e  47 62 6d 7c 04 6b 64 09  |.T`O\Vs^Gbm|.kd.|
00000090  42 7b 5e 5d 4b 76 5f 51  01 38 7c 7c 6c 4a 7a 66  |B{^]Kv_Q.8||lJzf|
000000a0  62 0d 53 61 4c 05 7a 55  63 00 6e 65 06 08 6d 00  |b.SaL.zUc.ne..m.|
000000b0  01 5a 51 6f 60 5b 7b 5b  79 57 57 00 05 5e 6b 0b  |.ZQo`[{[yWW..^k.|
000000c0  67 5a 6e 4b 7a 4b 7c 5f  62 00 69 6f 00 02 6c 01  |gZnKzK|_b.io..l.|
000000d0  71 50 56 5f 72 46 50 41  7c 04 51 01 03 4b 7c 5c  |qPV_rFPA|.Q..K|\|
000000e0  66 42 51 6f 63 48 3e 56  74 7e 41 51 77 7b 05 75  |fBQocH>Vt~AQw{.u|
000000f0  61 6b 07 7d 67 5f 07 7f  60 67 03 77 6d 03 50 7e  |ak.}g_..`g.wm.P~|
00000100  70 72 42 6b 6c 78 03 5a  58 64 4d 6a 01 0d 5d 50  |prBklx.ZXdMj..]P|
.....-
```

PK as the start of the magic byte is usually used by ZIP compression algorithms and their derivates. — But regular ZIP-decomressors cannot handle it, at least not further unpatched.

But looking at the code, it's obvious: This code is not compressed, just scrambled. Having a look at the present character in hex:

```bash
hexdump -ve '/1 "%02X\n"' payload.bin | sort -u | sed -z 's/\n/ /g; s/ 1/\n1/; s/ 2/\n2/;s/ 3/\n3/;s/ 4/\n4/;s/ 5/\n5/;s/ 6/\n6/;s/ 7/\n7/;'

00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E
32 38 39 3E 3F
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F
```

- Only 7 bit encoding present like ASCII.
- non-printable characters [00 - 0F] are present
- a continuous gap at [0F - 31]

A "Caesar cypher" / "rot(13)" is plausible: by shifting the gap to the non printable [00 - 0F], all present characters become printable (the characters below the gap get appended after the highest ones at a rot(XX) operation).

*How many characters to shift?* — A short look in the `man 7 ascii` helps:

The beginning of the printable characters are characters like `,.()*`. As only some of them are frequent in structured code the manual match of the short list of the [30 - 3F] is the next hint:

```
Real HEX   20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F
   ASCII      !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /
rot(-16)   ·· ·· 32 ·· ·· ·· ·· ·· 38 39 ·· ·· ·· ·· 3E 3F
rot(-18)   32 ·· ·· ·· ·· ·· 38 39 ·· ·· ·· ·· 3E 3F ·· ··
```

rot(-16) and rot(-18) could fit quite well.

Doing a rot(-16):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

file="payload.bin"
rot=-16

/usr/bin/printf "$(
    for i in $(
        hexdump -ve '/1 "%d "' "$file"
    ); do 
        i=$(( $i + $rot ));
        if [ $i -lt 1 ]; then
            i=$(( $i + 128 ));
        elif [ $i -gt 127 ]; then
            i=$(( $i - 128 ));
        fi;
        printf '\\x%x' $i;
    done
)\n"
```

Result rot(-16):

```
@;n2AFk2^eU1]pHIjBJKi8GBkViwZ_`ri8H0_fjHnAl1mOmyFqV4A^|N@OU=AjiKlD1umOUz_Uqr)PwwL@T]LmMh9R]l>CTq0ZwlsQ]htkJ?LX\XOJKPBAdn<[Ss9aO2sDP?LFcN7R]lt[Ty2kNM;fOAq(ll\:jVR}CQ<ujESp^Uvx]pqJA_PKkKiGGpuN[{WJ^;j;lORpY_pr\qa@FOb6@1ltAqs;lLV2A_S8.Fdn1AgkueQ[wmWOwoPWsg]s@n`b2[\hsJHT=Zq}M@SWJgLh7[pLMCS63IwIMn`bNCSPEQ]PtANDL(@ZQDFs}HBoc7^pVAjO^JA`kNhai8Fs}OBPo8@dz1AUpKlE_JFjmDian8YPk8EUz=]pVs@EcrEUz=/kNM:eQE7kNZIFINIRS{LFkZ<CShrLbT>kI8rkId4Kc{vX[b?CS{6aOMMo:|?nNWqaL5MC[fCC\`E"_eH8Z_o1^URAjO^JA`kNhaixDUuNFE|7^Qj~lIbO@EIH]T4>QOb2@E|KEQj;lO}8[{_NGLm8GppK)gLkwnIm0oMk0aHN>Zq03[vdsIR{1ZqZ5AvdJJbTOkI8H[S:9RV5MAd0MFcX5KHrMmJbg@IP:JwNO(jA2K]pe1FOHN@AltmNQyFO0HY_=1mK4AFjR8Bn|NFOeAGeRIjB5rGLUDian5@E|pEUQDFKmtjEA4.@qL6XWk0aH:2[qnuCS{6PwT1[Tb6XSSJgHXL@kfInghHR]X4[q^CFc{1RRvMmJbIQPlRIQh6[Un\(VrOb_UHnU{5DjpO`jIbSR\N:]IKmA8bkU]t4VT3\FO}ZYz53FTYlDWR[BoSO@rvYk8b7Py_Z@sQ]/QtFaLSJOGTqIClI7IOJLXkLnZwl[fm2<mTngl`N`[thpSHys[Rhu\`P=Wd}OFHW9Lb1=orLSPulE"SZ4PZDcTEdK{VLj6Yo_2iNYaPNVOQyWsQq3_hjH5GAt:jeO0_ImrjA2KGpQ:]q^N@Fk2FpwAjKm:)e<vunImLngh4QRl6[TLIZvwKJRWMmJbO@vr6Jblw[TD7CS63dHd1Xkb3CSSJdfh4XdRwkNMJe?FN(m\hw]Ufxh8O:YlkHiKj;lOu4YoS1mHLATTjTVy|CiVeZWam1jEWN@OOB_T}1Z_pL@UeF_QmtjFW;.kJ?LFSP3RfkrkIev[>W9gRdLlgepoSS9Q?kMDP?LFSP3RfkrkIev[>W9gRdLlgepoSS9Q?kMn`bu(EUrDFqVJAPdKkHfzk8OvmB`qjHYq/
```

Result rot(-18):

```
>9l0?Di0\cS/[nFGh@HIg6E@iTguX]^pg6F.]dhFl?j/kMkwDoT2?\zL>MS;?hgIjB/skMSx]Sop'NuuJ>R[JkKf7P[j<ARo.XujqO[friH=JVZVMHIN@?bl:YQq7_M0qBN=JDaL5P[jrYRw0iLK9dM?o&jjZ8hTP{AO:shCQn\Stv[noH?]NIiIgEEnsLYyUH\9h9jMPnW]npZo_>DM`4>/jr?oq9jJT0?]Q6,Dbl/?eiscOYukUMumNUqe[q>l^`0YZfqHFR;Xo{K>QUHeJf5YnJKAQ41GuGKl^`LAQNCO[Nr?LBJ&>XOBDq{F@ma5\nT?hM\H?^iLf_g6Dq{M@Nm6>bx/?SnIjC]HDhkBg_l6WNi6CSx;[nTq>CapCSx;-iLK8cOC5iLXGDGLGPQyJDiX:AQfpJ`R<iG6piGb2IaytVY`=AQy4_MKKm8z=lLUo_J3KAYdAAZ^C ]cF6X]m/\SP?hM\H?^iLf_gvBSsLDCz5\Oh|jG`M>CGF[R2<OM`0>CzICOh9jM{6Yy]LEJk6EnnI'eJiulGk.mKi._FL<Xo.1YtbqGPy/XoX3?tbHH`RMiG6FYQ87PT3K?b.KDaV3IFpKkH`e>GN8HuLM&h?0I[nc/DMFL>?jrkLOwDM.FW];/kI2?DhP6@lzLDMc?EcPGh@3pEJSBg_l3>CznCSOBDIkrhC?2,>oJ4VUi._F80YolsAQy4NuR/YR`4VQQHeFVJ>idGlefFP[V2Yo\ADay/PPtKkH`GONjPGOf4YSlZ&TpM`]SFlSy3BhnM^hG`QPZL8[GIk?6`iS[r2TR1ZDM{XWx31DRWjBUPY@mQM>ptWi6`5Nw]X>qO[-OrD_JQHMERoGAjG5GMHJViJlXujYdk0:kRlej^L^YrfnQFwqYPfsZ^N;Ub{MDFU7J`/;mpJQNsjC QX2NXBaRCbIyTJh4Wm]0gLW_NLTMOwUqOo1]fhF3E?r8hcM.]Gkph?0IEnO8[o\L>Di0Dnu?hIk8'c:tslGkJlef2OPj4YRJGXtuIHPUKkH`M>tp4H`juYRB5AQ41bFb/Vi`1AQQHbdf2VbPuiLKHc=DL&kZfu[Sdvf6M8WjiFgIh9jMs2WmQ/kFJ?RRhRTwzAgTcXU_k/hCUL>MM@]R{/X]nJ>ScD]OkrhDU9,iH=JDQN1PdipiGctY<U7ePbJjecnmQQ7O=iKBN=JDQN1PdipiGctY<U7ePbJjecnmQQ7O=iKl^`s&CSpBDoTH?NbIiFdxi6Mtk@^ohFWo-
```

Not really readable text. Also a structure is not noticeable at the first glance.
BTW: The other possibilities of rotation that produce only printable characters look similar.

*=> We've to add a step here or before the rot().*

Most plausible would be a XOR encryption. Therefore a second string is required as key.

The key can be a part of this data. But it also can be a data item set before/ after this "payload" item. It even can be the unique customer ID that might have been sent with this package or it is not sent because its a part of the app code / settings that is reproducible at the phone-home server.

*=> For more targeted tests, at least the whole phone-home transfer should be available, better the whole software settings. Else deeper analysis or brute force techniques are required.*